# How to add String Text to strongly typed views in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

How to add String Text to strongly typed views in MVC, for instance, I have got:

```
<div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.productWebsite, new { style = "width:300px;" })%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.productWebsite)%>
        </div>
```

I want to add "http://" to `model.productWebsite` so when user writes `www.abc.com` , on tryupdatemodel it should save as http://www.abc.com in the database.
            I tried doing something like :  `<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => "http://" + model.productWebsite, new { style = "width:300px;" })%>` which doesnt works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely this is something you should be handling within the controller when the model is being updated?

Like this:

```
public ActionResult Update(ModelClass model)
{
    if (!model.productWebsite.StartsWith("http://")
{
    model.productWebsite = "http://" + model.productWebsite 
}

}
```

Comment: Or on the model as Mike suggests. Probably better. D'oh.

Comment: but its strongly type view , so i cant get the value using form collection

Comment: This does not handle `https` or other protocols. I have left an answer that does.

Answer (score 3):

For this problem, it's easier just to modify the property itself:

```
private string _productWebsite;
public string ProductWebstring
{
  get { return _productWebsite; }
  set 
  {
    _productWebsite = value;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_productWebsite) && !_productWebsite.StartsWith("http"))
    {
      _productWebsite = "http://" + _productWebsite;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where should i define this property

Comment: In the Model. The Model that the View is strongly-typed to.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do it yourself inside controller - you can use **[Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** class.

Also, try marking your property in the model with **[DataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype.aspx)** attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The answers you have hit the nail on the head, do it in your Model. But their implementation is slightly wrong, what if you have a `https` link or, less commonly, an `ftp` link.

I would suggest this...

```
if (!model.productWebsite.Contains("://"))
{
    model.productWebsite = string.format("http://{0}", model.productWebsite);
}
```

This checks for the protocol suffix and if it is not present attaches a default of `http`